# How to avoid later content appear before a subfloat figure?

Tags: subfloats

My LaTeX is like this:

```
Here is the result figure:

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \subfloat[Original]{\includegraphics[foo.png]}
    %...
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

(Content after the figure but shown before the figure)
```

If there can be too much space below the figure, LaTeX will move the content after the figure backward to before the figure. How to change this behavior, i.e., ensure there's no other content between the line "Here is the result figure" and the actual figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `\usepackage{here}`
then

```
\begin{figure}[H]% uppercase H 
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \subfloat[Original]{\includegraphics[foo.png]}
    %...
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```